# Deleting users from a table

Tags: postgresql

I made a table that accepts id, name, email and password. When I first made the database I was having issues with inputting the names onto the table but now that is fixed and I'm left with many users that have blank names in the database so I'm trying to delete them. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DELETE` to delete rows:

```
delete from that_table
where name is null
  or trim(name) = '' --<< empty string is "blank"
```